# Avalanche Breakdown Noise as digital input

Tags: function-generator, random

I am trying to develop a true random number generator using reverse biased transistors avalance breakdown noise as a input for pic microcontroller. How can i turn the noise in to a digital input ? Is it possible ?  If i program the pic for make a digital input read , shall i say 100 times in a second , is it possible to digitize as 1 and 0 ?

Answer (score 4):

Start by AC-coupling the signal, then amplifying that.  You could then use a typical *data slicer*, which compares the instantaneous signal to a low-pass filtered version of itself.  Then you sample this digital signal whenever you need a new random bit.

Be very careful that the noise from the digital circuitry doesn't feed back into the analog signal somehow.  If it does, the analog section is no longer statistically independent, and the result therefore not truly random.